# Проблема с margin у которого значение в процентах

Tags: html, css, sass, responsive

Не могу понять почему когда задаешь margin-right в процентах  отступ не применяется.Хотел сверстать адаптивную страничку
**Вот html:**

```
<footer class="container clearfix">
    <button> <i class="fa fa-arrow-left"></i> previous</button>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-paper-plane"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-dribbble"></a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="fa fa-behance"></a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

**Вот sass:**

```
footer {
    padding: 80px 0 50px 0;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #a5a5a5;

    button {
        padding: 10px 02.56797583081571% 10px 03.62537764350453%;
        letter-spacing: 1px;
        font:600 0.813em 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
        background-color: #000;
        color: #fff;
        border-radius: 5px;
        border: none;
    }
    ul {
        float: right;

        li {
            display: inline;
            margin-right: 04.82315112540193%;

            a {
                color: inherit;
                text-decoration: none;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ширина окна  1350px;
Ширина .container 662px это 49.037%
index.htm
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
А в psd должно выгяледить так
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для элемента `ul` нужно задать `width`, если используете `float`.

Comment: оу, оу,  блиннн спасибо